# Mass - Unification of inertial and gravitational definitions

Tags: general-relativity, mass, mass-energy

As a kinetic definition, mass of a body is a measure of the translational inertia of the body. There is also the gravitational definition of mass. Can these definitions (inertial and gravitational) empirically be proved to be equivalent? Also, are these definitions applicable on a quantum scale? Finally, if the 2 definitions of mass are empirically equivalent, can a single definition be made to encompass the 2?

Comment: There are inertial mass as defined by Newton's second law and gravitational mass as defined by Newton's law of gravity and general relativity. They are assumed to be equivalent but we can't exclude the possibility that they are not.

Comment: There are no changes to the above in quantum mechanics. Your initial question of finding the most general theoretical definition is somewhat nonsensical, though. Theoretical definitions in physics are merely descriptions of empirical reality. We are finding two substantially different empirical facts for the behavior of "mass", which are inertial and gravitational. We are not finding a numerical difference between both within the current experimental limits, hence we link both with the equivalence principle.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Amount of substance itself is a physical quantity. You can check it here at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_physical_quantities. So this is not an appropriate definition of mass. Rather mass should be defined as a measure of inertia (inertial mass) or as a property of a physical body which determines the strength of its mutual gravitational attraction to other bodies (gravitational mass).

Comment: "Can these definitions (kinetic and gravitational) be proved to be empirically equivalent?" Yes: this is precisely the purpose of the [Eötvös experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment)

Comment: `F=ma w=mg` if `a=g -> F=w`

Comment: @ldgorman if only life was that simple.

Comment: Einstein's photon by the moon's gravitational force was distracted in its direction, but was not accelerated. This might lead to think of gravitational force not fitting the "kinetic definition" in respect of photons.  But then, rest mass of photon is zero, and any inertial mass shouldn't do either.

Comment: @PeterBernhard any change in velocity, even if not in the magnitude but just in the direction, constitutes an acceleration (they are both vector quantities). Also, inertia is more dependent on momentum than mass alone, as it is a kinetic quantity. Photons may be massless but they have momentum and thus inertia.

Comment: Have you reference? "Photons may be massless but they have momentum and thus inertia." Inertia means you need force for change. Conversely though, force must cause change. In fact, zero mass, but inertia in respect of direction, bias to the moon. This is what the concept "rest mass" is about? If a photon cannot be accelerated in velocity - it would not have inertia in that respect, of velocity. Rest mass zero photon is inert in respect of direction not velocity. By definition, both should be encompassed. Is "inertia, not mass" a personal concept of yours?

Comment: @PeterBernhard Force can be applied but it may not cause change - you can apply quite a lot of force on a wall but you wouldn't change anything about it. When it comes to explaining photon trajectories in space, classical mechanics is woefully inappropriate (and inadequate), and forces must be represented as distortions induced into spacetime, which redefine "straight line" paths followed by photons. In a classical sense, you have flipped your concepts - photons can change direction, but not speed, in vacuum. Forces applied to a photon can only affect its path in vacuum, not its speed.

Comment: Now if you have photons travelling through media, all bets are off in this regard. Again, all of your questions are better off as actual questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori, they could have been different things.  The Equivalence Principle - the hypothesis that they are actually the same - is a core input to the theory of General Relativity.  To the extent that General Relativity is empirically validated, we have evidence that these really are the same.

There's no complete theory of quantum gravity, so I think we'd have to say that we don't know if the equivalence really holds all the way to the quantum scale.

Comment: Inspired by your question:  Inertial masses put on an old fashioned scale seem to relate to a "third" mass, which is the gravitational mass (of the earth). However, looking at inertial mass in space that ideally does not have gravitational "ground" for such scaling -  the leverage remains the same. Thus, I came about to believe in "space" (encompassing gravitational and inertial mass situations) being subject to that same force underlying both concepts of mass. Henceforth, I personally think of space as on  "a move". And: Gravitation - self centered, Inertial mass -more  subject to "quantum".